# Why can NSolve only solve this system of equations after trivial substitution?

Tags: equation-solving

The first system immediately yields {}, but the second, equivalent, system yields the solution `{{k -> 4.96048, tl1 -> 1.64842, tl2 -> 2.07466}}` :

```
NSolve[{
  (5 - k)(2940/100) == tl1^0.3, 
  (5 - k)(3150/100) == tl2^0.3, 
  4200 tl1^0.7 + 4500 tl2^0.7 == 1000000}, 
  {k, tl1, tl2}]

NSolve[{
  (5-k)(2940/100) == tl1^0.3,
  (5-k)(3150/100) == tl2^0.3, 
  (5-k) 4200(2940/100)^(7/3) + (5-k) 4500 (3150/100)^(7/3) == 1000000}, 
  {k, tl1, tl2}]
```

The second system is created by noting that `tl1^0.7 = (tl1^0.3)^(7/3)` and `tl2^0.7 = (tl2^0.3)^(7/3)` and substituting the results into the third equation. Is there a way to get *Mathematica* to do such substitutions on its own?

Comment: You can check that the solution to the second system is not solution to the first.  Try `NSolve[{(5 - k) (2940/100) == tl1^(3/10), (5 - k) (3150/100) == tl2^(3/10), 4200 tl1^(7/10) + 4500 tl2^(7/10) == 1000000}, {k, tl1, tl2}]` instead of the first system.

Comment: Indeed, I goofed. The 3rd equation should have been 4200 ((5-k)(2940/100))^(7/3) + 4500 ((5-k) (3150/100))^(7/3) == 1000000. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a way to get Mathematica to do such substitutions on its own?".

The answer to this question is: yes. Just use `Solve` and exact numbers.

```
Solve[{
    (5 - k) (2940/100) == tl1^(3/10),
    (5 - k) (3150/100) == tl2^(3/10),
    4200 tl1^(7/10) + 4500 tl2^(7/10) == 1000000},
  {k, tl1, tl2}, Reals] // N
```

> ```
> {{k -> 4.74961, tl1 -> 776.036, tl2 -> 976.695}}
> ```

Note: your two systems of equations are not equivalent.

Comment: Thank you @m_goldberg, I now see the importance of avoiding decimals. Help much appreciated!